# How to create a Room using api in Mesibo

Tags: mesibo

How to create a room using rest API in mesibo so that we can generate the room id and secret and send it to users. Basically, the use case is

I want to use mesibo for the tutoring sessions. So we need a way to be able to create a link within the tutoring app that will bring the user directly into the correct conference. The Mesibo demo currently asks for the person's name, room number, etc. We don't want any questions asked. It should go straight from the application portal to the Mesibo conference. So the link can contain the encrypted information about the conference, such as the person's name, the room number, and the start time. Once the tutoring session is over, the links should stop working; each link should be good for only that one conference, and it should expire after.

I have successfully created the create user, regenerate user token, create group API I want to move forward to create room and let people join it.

Let me know if that's a possible cause in the documentation it's not mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

a conference room is a mesibo group. The participants are members of a group. To create a conference room, you essentially need to create a mesibo group and add participants to it. Refer to the documentation here, it has one entire section on creating room using APIs

https://mesibo.com/documentation/api/conferencing/